# InvalidCastException in Linq to entities query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am making an application for my department at work. I have run into a big problem.

I am trying to get the primary key of a name selected on a ListBox control. This ListBox control is populated from a query from the database when the form loads. Below is the query used to populate the ListBox control.

```
Dim examinationOfficer As New ExamOfficerPayEntities
Dim findOfficer = From officer In examinationOfficer.Exams_Officer
Order By officer.First_Name Ascending
Select officer.First_Name.ToUpper & " " & officer.Last_Name.ToUpper

lstFullname.DataSource = findOfficer.ToList
lstFullname.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

The query works fine and the ListBox is populated as expected. The problem is I am trying to get the value of the primary key of the selected ListBox item. The primary key value I am trying to retrieve is an integer value and it is set as an `identity`.

Below is a summary of my database.

Table `Exam_Officer`:

```
Officer_ID as int which is the primary key and is also set as an identity column
First_Name as nvarchar
last_Name as nvarchar
```

One other Table is `Result_Submitted`, 
its columns are:

```
sn as integer primary key and an identity column
Officer_ID as an int and is a foreign key to the Table Exam_Officer
Result_Submitted as nvarchar
Outstanding_Result as nvarchar
```

This is the code I am trying to use to get the `officer_ID` from the `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox control of a Windows form.

```
Dim selectedOfficer As Exams_Officer = DirectCast(lstFullname.SelectedItem,     Exams_Officer)
Dim selectedOfficerID As Integer = selectedOfficer.Officer_ID
The code dosen't work it throws an error on the first line (directcast method)

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type    'EXAMINATION_OFFICER_PAYMENT.Exams_Officer'.
Source=EXAMINATION OFFICER PAYMENT
```

I am confused and don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm surprised it's even displaying at the moment as `FullName` isn't a property of `String`. Look at your code:

```
Dim examinationOfficer As New ExamOfficerPayEntities
Dim findOfficer = From officer In examinationOfficer.Exams_Officer
Order By officer.First_Name Ascending
Select officer.First_Name.ToUpper & " " & officer.Last_Name.ToUpper
```

You're selecting the full name - so the result of your code is just the names, not the original officers. I suspect you want:

```
Dim examinationOfficer As New ExamOfficerPayEntities
Dim findOfficer = From officer In examinationOfficer.Exams_Officer
                  Order By officer.First_Name Ascending

lstFullname.DataSource = findOfficer.ToList
lstFullname.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

At that point, you've got a list of officers rather than a list of strings. This is assuming `FullName` is a property of your officer type though. If it's not, you might want to project to a list where you do the string concatenation in one property, but keep the original officer in another property. For example:

```
Dim examinationOfficer As New ExamOfficerPayEntities
Dim findOfficer = From officer In examinationOfficer.Exams_Officer
    Order By officer.First_Name Ascending
    Select New With {
        .FullName = officer.First_Name.ToUpper & " " _ & officer.Last_Name.ToUpper,
        .Officer = officer
    }

lstFullname.DataSource = findOfficer.ToList
lstFullname.DisplayMember = "FullName"
```

Then later, you'd need to extract the value of the `Officer` property to get at the officer object itself.

Comment: Thank you sir i have done what you said.The error now is Unable to   cast object of type   'VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.String,EXAMINATION_OFFICER_PAYMENT.Exams_Officer]' to type 'EXAMINATION_OFFICER_PAYMENT.Exams_Officer'. Please i can now access all the properties of the officer object but it still refuse to get the officer_ID property when i do the directcast.I am a noob at this i am still learning.Thanks for all your efforts.

Comment: @JamesOshomah: That suggests you're not actually fetching the `Officer` property as I said in the final sentence.

Comment: please can you show me how to go about it.Honestly i don't know what to do again.Thanks and may God bless you for your time and effort

Comment: @JamesOshomah: Certainly not right now, I'm afraid - and I couldn't swear to get the syntax right in VB anyway without a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

In general the way to do this is to add Officers to your ListBox and override Officer's ToString() method to return FullName, or bind and set DisplayMember to Fullname. Like Jon Skeet, I'm not sure why the code you've posted is working...

Then you can do

```
Dim selectedOfficer As Exams_Officer = DirectCast(lstFullname.SelectedItem, Exams_Officer)
```

and `Exams_Officer.OfficeID` will be okay.

At the moment you are casting a string to an Officer, the above casts an Object to an Officer, which is more likely to work.

Bear in mind however that you need to instance all your officers and that they'll be in memory. So if had a lot of and/or Officer was a hefty object, performance might start to suffer.
The simplest option at that point is a small class / structure with just ID and name in it.